# Code-Golf: Farey sequence (I) 

Tags: code-golf, math

### Challenge

> In this task you would be given an integer N
>   (less than 10^5), output the [Farey
>   sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) of order N.

The input N is given in a single line,the inputs are terminated by EOF.

**Input**

```
4
3
1
2
```

**Output**

```
F4 = {0/1, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1/1}
F3 = {0/1, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1/1}
F1 = {0/1, 1/1}
F2 = {0/1, 1/2, 1/1}
```

**Constraints**

- The number of inputs would not exceed 10^6 values
- You can use any language of your choice
- Shortest solution wins!

Comment: This will get loooong.....the output i mean.

Comment: Is N=0 permitted?

Comment: What's with the »(I)« in the title?

Comment: I think you should reconsider the input limitations, the 10^5 order Farey sequence consist of approximately 3 billion numbers, and one million inputs is way too much.

Comment: @Joey: Hmm. there's a Farey Sequence (II) now.  Must be first edition! :-)

Comment: @mellamokb: Well, that one's a code challenge, though, so no title clash in any case. But yes, that sort of answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

### J, 96

```
('F',],' = {0/1',', 1/1}',~('r';'/')rplc~', ',"1":"0@(3 :'}./:~~.,(%~}:\)i.1x+y')&".);._2(1!:1)3
```

( `/:~~.,(%~}:\)i.>:x:y` gives the list; the rest is I/O and formatting (with bad style))

E.g:

```
4
3
1
2
F4 = {0/1, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1/1}
F3 = {0/1, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1/1}          
F1 = {0/1, 1/1}                         
F2 = {0/1, 1/2, 1/1}
```

#### Edits

- **(114 → 106)**  Clearer appending `,`
- **(106 → 105)**  Cap `[:` to At `@`
- **(105 → 101)**  Delete superfluous `":` conversion
- **(101 → 99)**  Use infix `\` for the list
- **(99 → 96)**

Comment: I get `|value error: rplc`. Are you sure you didn't `load 'strings'` earlier in the session and forget about it?

Comment: @Jesse: absolutely. I (almost) never use `'strings'`. I just use the default linux-j-7.01 environment.

Comment: Ugh... I switched to j602 for `wd` and now I may need to switch back. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 186 Chars

```py
import sys
p=sys.stdout.write
while 1:
 a=0;b=c=x=1;d=y=N=input();p("F%d = {%d/%d, %d/%d"%(d,a,b,c,d))
 while y-1:x=(b+N)/d*c-a;y=(b+N)/d*d-b;p(", %d/%d"%(x,y));a=c;c=x;b=d;d=y
 p("}\n")
```

Comment: +1,but are you sure this will be fast for 10^6 number of inputs?

Comment: @Debanjan No. It would be really slow for 10^6 inputs. It is linear in complexity (in terms of the number of terms), though.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 156

```lisp
(do((l()()))((not(set'n(read()()))))(dotimes(j n)(dotimes(i(1+ j))(push(/(1+ i
)(1+ j))l)))(format t"~&F~D = {0/1~{, ~A~}/1}"n(sort(delete-duplicates l)'<)))
```

(newlines not necessary)

Very brutal, but languages with native rationals are an invitation to that.

**Ungolfed with comments:**

```lisp
                                        ; at each iteration:
(do ((l()()))                           ; - reset l to nil
    ((not (set 'n (read()()))))         ; - read a term (nil for eof)
                                        ;   assign it to n
                                        ;   stop looping if nil
  (dotimes (j n)                        ; for j in 0..n-1
    (dotimes (i (1+ j))                 ;   for i in 0..j
      (push (/ (1+ i) (1+ j)) l)))      ;     prepend i+1/j+1 to l
  (format t "~&F~D = {0/1~{, ~A~}/1}"   ; on a new line, including 0/1,
                                        ; forcing the format for 1
          n                             ; print sequence index, and
          (sort                         ; sorted sequence of
           (delete-duplicates l)        ;   unique fractions
           '<)))                        ; (in ascending order)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>110</strike> <strike>108</strike> <strike>102</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>94</strike> <strike>92</strike> <strike>91</strike> 89

```
#!ruby -lp
$_="F#$_ = {#{a=[];1.upto(eval$_){|d|a|=(0..d).map{|n|n.quo d}};a.sort*', '}}"
```

Comment: I think you should output "0/1" and "1/1" instead of "0" and "1" respectively. Also, does this only work for ruby 1.9?

Comment: @Eelvex: It does output 0/1 and 1/1 on my system. And yes, it requires 1.9 (because of the character literals).

Answer (score 2):

## J, <strike>156</strike> <strike>135</strike> <strike>117</strike> 112

```
d=:3 :0
wd;'F';(":y);' = {';(}.,(', ';2|.'/';|.)"1(<@":)"0(2)x:/:~~.,(-.@>*%)"0/~i.x:>:y),<'}'
)
d@".;._2(1!:1)3
```

j602 or similar (`wd`). Input on stdin, output on stdout.

Still puzzling over how to golf the output code, which is 100 characters or so.

Edit: (156->135) Tacit->explicit for long monadic verb chains, less braindead list generation

Edit: (135->117) Found [raze](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d330.htm). Took me long enough. Switched string handling around.

Edit: (117->112) Slightly less braindead way to exclude fractions above 1. Unnecessary open.

Comment: Maybe you can omit one of your two `x:`s?

Comment: @Eelvex: The left one is 2&x:, e.g. split a rational number into numerator and denominator.

Comment: oic. Pity ... :(

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript (101)

```
~:c[,{){.}c(*}%.c/zip{+}*]zip{~{.@\%.}do;1=},{~<},{~\10c?*\/}${'/'*}%', '*'F'c`+' = {0/1, '+\', 1/1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 145 bytes

```hs
f(!)(%)n|p<-product[1..n]='F':n!" = {"++unwords[i%g!"/"++p%g![",}"!!(i%p)]|i<-[0..p],g<-[gcd i p],p<=n*g]
m@main=readLn>>=putStrLn.f shows div>>m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dci7DoMgAEDRna8AEqNWpbWvoRHSqVO3jsbBiCKpIgGtQ@23U7Zzb1/bdzsMznURiqMgVpsuMm0mvjRzmROiKho@wptCGFL4xUmyqHUy3JYyEAjv/dAeJU5/GKFIBjquNllk5YEQXaXCSzQcSuhDF1TtRAXG@1hLRU1b86dijOplfs3mqUgHbT@tFnL5YWx0LgdHcAJncAHXPw)

This reduces all of \$\left\{\frac{0}{n!}, \frac{1}{n!}, \dots, \frac{n!}{n!}\right\}\$ and selects the ones with denominator \$\leq n\$.

(The byte count went up a little again because I noticed the problem asks to handle multiple lines of input.)

The other Haskell answer is missing some imports and is missing `1/1` in the output. It also doesn't take multiple lines of input. When fixed, it comes out to 188 bytes:

```hs
import GHC.Real
import Data.List
f n="F"++show n++" = {"++(intercalate", ".("0/1":).map(\(i:%d)->show i++"/"++show d).sort.nub$[i%d|d<-[1..n],i<-[1..d]])++"}"
m@main=readLn>>=putStrLn.f>>m
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 148

```hsk
f n="F"++show n++" = {"++(intercalate", ".("0/1":).map(\(i:%d)->show i++"/"++show d).sort.nub$[i%d|d<-[1..n],i<-[1..d-1]])++"}"
main=interact$f.read
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 55 bytes

```
mλ:'F+s¹+" = "σ"1]""1/1}"σ"[0""{0/1"sOutfεmF/π2ŀ→)fImi¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fcbit1N@3iQzu1lRRsFZTONysZxiopGeob1oLY0QZKStUG@oZKxf6lJWnntua66Z9vMDra8KhtkmaaZ27moW3///834TLmMuQyAgA)

It was interesting messing with strings in Husk.

This gives the exact required output for the given test case.

There's a strange husk-ism in the `mi¶` function that gives intermediate 0's in the output. Hence, those are filtered out. [Here's an explanation from Zgarb.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55983590#55983590)

### Explanation

```
mλ:'F+s¹+" = "σ"1]""1/1}"σ"[0""{0/1"sOutfεmF/π2ŀ→)fImi¶
                                                      ¶ split input on newlines
                                                    mi  map to integers
                                                  fI    filter out zeroes
mλ                                               )      map each number through this function:
                                               ŀ→       range (0..n)
                                             π2         all possible pairs
                                          mF/           map each to it's fraction
                                        fε              keep elements ≤ 1
                                       t                remove first value (Any)
                                     Ou                 uniquify, sort ascending
                                    s                   convert to string
                         σ"[0""{0/1"                    change 0 → 0/1
              σ"1]""1/1}"                               change 1 → 1/1
        +" = "                                          add an equal sign
  :'F+s¹                                                prepend "F{N}"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 44 bytes

```
ƓµŻœċ2g/’$Ðḟ÷/Þj€”/j⁾, ,⁸Ø<,y“F> = {<}”Ṅ
Ç1¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVoApf9qZWxsef//xpPCtcW7xZPEizJnL@KAmSTDkOG4n8O3L8OeauKCrOKAnS9q4oG@LCAs4oG4w5g8LHnigJxGPiA9IHs8feKAneG5hArDhzHCv///NAozCjEKMv8)

Could probably be improved if someone told me how to read and write multiline input properly in Jelly. I couldn't find any documentation on it, so I just have a while(true) loop that errors out when it reaches EOF.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 89 bytes

```python
lambda n:[*zip(*sorted({j/i:(j,i)for i in range(n,0,-1)for j in range(i+1)}.items()))][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixDoMgEADQX2G8s9SW6GTSL0EHGkGP6EGQRY3fjkmXvvHFPc@Bm@I@fVnM@h2N4E5XB0WotpCyHeH0L@rAS0IXkiBBLJLhyQLLt3yq3/r/0kPhVVO26waIOGg1lJiIMzhoEcsN)

Basically generating all possible fractions and then using a dictionary comprehension to filter out the duplicates.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 142 bytes

```python
while 1:n=input();print('F%s = {'%n+', '.join([*zip(*sorted({j/i:f'{j}/{i}'for i in range(int(n),0,-1)for j in range(i+1)}.items()))][1])+'}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxDoIwEADQna/oQq4nCFacMKz@BGEwscg1em1KjdGm317D5vyS5z5hsdzl/F7ooYXqeSB2ryDx7DxxkHApVzGICCVXUAtojCWW4@5LTu5W64O@yWha6meIJrWREszWCxLEwl/5ruW2MNaHeq9wI/NHlcLUUNDPVSLiNKoJK0iAOZ@KrlDF8Qc)

Abiding by all of the I/O requirements

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 73 bytes

```
'Fqi:T" = {"[[T1]Y,{_'\*',+\W%@_@_2$+2%Ta.+:/@f*\.-_1=T)<@W%\}g'\*\;]S*'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X92tMNMqREnBVqFaKTo6xDA2Uqc6Xj1GS11HOyZc1SHeId5IRdtINSRRT9tK3yFNK0ZPN97QNkTTxiFcNaY2Hagyxjo2WEu99v9/CwA)

Uses an algorithm to generate the terms in traditional order. A lot of maps and vector functions were used here. If anyone wants a write-up then I'll make one, unless I can figure out a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica <s>13</s> 78 bytes

```
Column[Row@{"F",#," = ",FareySequence[ToExpression@#]}&/@StringSplit[#,"\n"]]&
```

---

**Example**

```
Column[Row@{#," = ",FareySequence[ToExpression@#]}&/@StringSplit[#,"\n"]]&["5\n4\n3"]
```

[image: Farey sequence]

Comment: It's nice that you have a builtin, but the spec asks for a specific formatting and handling multiple queries.

Comment: Kindly explain what you mean by "specific formatting and handling multiple queries".

Comment: Per the specification, you have to find Farey sequences for multiple integers separated by newlines and output them in the format "F3 = {0/1, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1/1}". Your code takes only one integer and has a different output format.

Comment: @xigoi, I think I've now addressed your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 40 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|εÝ2.Æ2Å1ª.¡`/}€нΣ`/}'/ý„, ýy"Fÿ = {ÿ}",
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AVMArP9vc2FiaWX//3zOtcOdMi7DhjLDhTHCqi7CoWAvfeKCrNC9zqNgL30nL8O94oCeLCDDvXkiRsO/ID0ge8O/fSIs//80CjMKMQoy/y0tbm8tbGF6eQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
|                     # Get all input-lines as a list
 ε                    # Map over each input-integer:
  Ý                   #  Pop and push a list in the range [0,n]
   2.Æ                #  Get all 2-element combinations of this list
      2Å1ª            #  Append pair [1,1]
  .¡                  #  Group the pairs by:
    `                 #   Pop and push both values separated to the stack
     /                #   Divide them
   }€                 #  After the group-by: map over each group
     н                #   Only leave the first pair of each group
      Σ  }            #  Then sort the pairs by:
       `/             #   Similar as above: dump and divide
  '/ý                '#  Then join each inner pair with "/"-delimiter
     „, ý             #  Join these strings with ", "-delimiter
         y            #  Push the current map-integer
          "Fÿ = {ÿ}"  #  Push this string, where the `ÿ` are automatically filled with
                      #  the integer and formatted list
                    , #  Pop and output it with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>18</s> 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Stupid old challenges and their stupid & unnecessarily strict I/O requirements costing me 20 bytes!

```
N£"F{X} = \{{Xõ c_ô+'/+ZÃü!xO mÎqSi,}}
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=TqMiRntYfSA9IFx7e1j1IGNf9CsnLytaw/wheE8gbc5xU2ksfX0&input=NAozCjEKMg)

```
N£"F{X} = \{{Xõ c_ô+'/+ZÃü!xO mÎqSi,}}
N                                          :Array of all inputs
 £                                         :Map each X
  "F   = \{                          }     :  Build a string
    {X}                                    :  Interpolate X
           {                               :  Interpolate
            Xõ                             :    Range [1,X]
                c                          :    Flat map by
                 _                         :    Passing each Z through the following function
                  ô                        :      Range [0,Z]
                   +'/+Z                   :      Append "/" followed by Z to each
                        Ã                  :    End map
                         ü                 :    Group & sort by
                          !xO              :      Evaluating each as JavaScript
                              m            :    Map
                               Î           :      First element
                                q          :    Join with
                                 S         :      Space
                                  i,       :      Prepend comma
                                    }      :  End interpolation
                                           :Implicit output joined with new lines
```

Comment: "_OK, what am I missing?_" There are multiple inputs, separated by newlines from STDIN. And the STDOUT output format you see in the challenge description is mandatory, with the `F# = {comma_and_space_separated_results}`.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen. Stupid old challenges and their stupid & unnecessarily strict I/O requirements!

Comment: Ikr.. :/ Ah well, you're still the shortest. ;p Group-and-sort by is way too long in 05AB1E (2 separated builtins)..