# Print ascending proper fractions using integers up to the given input

Tags: code-golf, rational-numbers

User inputs an integer. Print out proper fractions using all positive integers up to the user's input, in ascending order.

Rule 1: Eliminate equal fractions.

Rule 2: Fractions should be in their simplest form.

Rule 3: Use "/" as a fraction symbol and next line (\n or \r as convenient) as a separator between fractions.

Winning Criteria: The shortest code wins.

For example:

4:

```
1/4
1/3
1/2
2/3
3/4
1
```

6:

```
1/6
1/5
1/4
1/3
2/5
1/2
3/5
2/3
3/4
4/5
5/6
1
```

Comment: i would recommend relaxing or removing rule 3, this site values loose input/output constraints. outputting as a list of fractions isnt much different than outputting fractions one per each line, and it probably doesnt add much to the challenge to require a specific format

Comment: wouldnt the example for 4 end with `...3/4, 1, 2, 3, 4`? same idea for 6... Also, if you want to include numbers like 1 (which isnt a fraction) maybe change the wording from "fractions" to "rationals". Otherwise, it should probably end before 1

Comment: @thejonymyster isn't it all fractions less than or equal to 1 in simplified form? It seems ok to me

Comment: @thejonymyster 2, 3, and 4 are not proper fractions. "Print out proper fractions using all integers up to the user's input, in ascending order." 1 is a proper fraction, though.

Comment: These are also called [Farey sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about this, voting to leave open.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question because it doesn't have a winning criterion. And, [please don't edit one in unless you're the question poster](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14840/20260).

Comment: @graffe While I don't know what the situation is for this question, in my general experience the majority of nice questions without a winning criterion posted by new contributors are, unfortunately, taken from another programming site or are homework.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please be aware we have a [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can post drafts of your questions so that others can give feedback and suggest ways to make your challenge clearer before you post it.

Comment: @Steffan that is surprising to me, i did not know that both A) 1 was a proper fraction and B) numbers higher than 1 wouldn't be. In the interest of clarity, I think a brief (maybe single sentence or less) definition of "proper fraction" would be good to include in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code-Golf: Farey sequence (I)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/code-golf-farey-sequence-i)

Comment: @thejonymyster After looking it up, I guess I was wrong, 1 is not a proper fraction. I thought pretty much everybody knew what a proper fraction was.

Comment: The [other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/code-golf-farey-sequence-i) has *extremely* strict output and input format, so I'd close it. It requires you to take input from STDIN, and then parse each line, and output in a very specific manner.

Comment: @xnor Whoops. I did not see at all that there was no winning criterion. I wouldn't have answered if I had.

Comment: @Arnauld isn't it obviously code-golf?

Comment: @graffe No, it's not. While most challenges on this site are [tag:code-golf], not all of them are, and that assumption cannot be made. It makes absolutely no sense to me why people are engaging in special pleading to give someone who clearly doesn't understand the rules and purpose of the site more reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
¶OfεuΣ´Ṫ/ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr///Ctk9mzrV1zqPCtOG5qi/huKP///82)

```
          ḣ # 1..input
       ´    # argdup: use this range twice
        Ṫ   # to construct a table
         /  # of one element divided by the other
            # (Husk will automatically simplify the fractions);
      Σ     # now flatten the table to a list
     u      # and keep only the unique elements,
   f        # filter to keep only those
    ε       # with value at most 1,
  O         # sort in ascending order,
 ¶          # and split by newlines
```

(or, also 10 bytes: `` ¶uOṁṠM`/ḣḣ `` [try it](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9C2Uv@HOxsf7lzgm6D/cMdiIPr//78ZAA))

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

Based on [the algorithm given in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Next_term).

```javascript
f=(d,a,b=(n=d,1),c=1)=>a^b?[a&&a+`/${b}
`]+f((k=(n+b)/d|0)*d-b,c,d,k*c-~~a):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpLDoIwEADQPadgYWCGTsUmxoVJ9SB@wrQDRCGtEeNG5erVrev3rvzkyd8vt4cOUdqUOgtCTM5CsEIGyVuDdsdntz9wUbBq6sXLfbLmpDqA4deUw1reK6xEO/IkNFRezzPj1iQfwxTHdjnGHjpYY67y8hhKzP5hg5i@)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  d,              //   the input n and the parameters (a, b, c, d)
  a,              //   which are initially set to:
  b = (n = d, 1), //   (undefined, 1, 1, n)
  c = 1           //
) =>              //
a ^ b ?           // if a is not equal to b:
  [ a &&          //   append either a + '/' + b + '\n' if a is defined
    a + `/${b}\n` //   or just an empty string if a is undefined (which
  ] +             //   happens only for the first iteration)
  f(              //   append the result of a recursive call:
    (k = (n + b)  //     set k = floor((n + b) / d)
         / d | 0) //
    * d - b,      //     update d to k * d - b
    c,            //     update a to c
    d,            //     update b to d
    k * c - ~~a   //     update c to k * c - a
                  //     (with a coerced to 0 if undefined)
  )               //   end of recursive call
:                 // else:
  1               //   stop the recursion and append the final '1'
```

Comment: Super cool. What's happening with `a=!(n=d)`? I just can't figure out what's going on there and I'm not sure what to search. Is it declaring two parameters, a and n and setting the default value of a to true if... n and d are 0?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl It sets `n` to the value of `d`, and then sets `a` to true if `n` is 0, or false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 56 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{↑↑'1',⍨(⊣,'/',⊢)⍥⍕/¨m[⍋÷/¨m←w/⍨≠÷/¨w←⊃⍵,.(¯1↓,¨)⍨,\⍵]}⍳
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37UNhGI1A3VdR71rtB41LVYR10fyO5apPmod@mj3qn6h1bkRj/q7T68HcR61DahXB@o8FHnArBAOVDgUVfzo96tOnoah9YbPmqbrHNoBVDrCp0YoGBs7aPezQA&f=S1Mw4UpTMAMA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289#9289), 77 bytes

Very direct port of the [code from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Next_term)

-4 bytes thanks to [Raztime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)

```ruby
->n{a,b,d=0,c=1,n
dw{k=(n+b)/d
a,b,c,d=c,d,k*c-a,k*d-b
sa b<2?a:a*1r/b
n>=c}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVZbb9s2FH73rzh10lhyFTneDUNQN70gxfawFWiBPczwBIqibTYSJZBUUltS_8he-tD9qO3X7JCU5EvTosMM2KTP_fKdI_35UZbx5sM_A0JTohS8it8yqgcAT5-u8nQZrYlawwyqZoC0WybjXLEATn-7fv381Ztr5HTXAARPUSZhS8iYXudJlHGluFhBFsCYBHAWIxtAo9Ke8TnMka9YugxtBAtYQF3PICOarlE7csaUl_nzi4W1wJdo5OwMnD2AKFJMJFHkaePIh6oeE7lSdcsGiMOYiwSNheyWpN6wkDmtahuCdZMQTWo4fY-RHRKhGfohJWnqnb73jd_T93tGLcO68ltqY0-WKtYSNFwdhWfq4MMlqLJg0omLZND97hW2Lfagq-lxPRTKjEYBZHiaSEicso7p4pHImfxxUqlQ55EKV6qMvUk48auhF46v_CE8gtdsxd4VIVOUFMw7PfObZmJ1s3AlWeFJP1S51FG8gSSHmnc15c6kDcoIobouJTOUwju7VHzLfHj8GPhRhm0yrt25ULoHCf0MOGjwFdigAVhrRGjVw0QDEQlIhoEJx45WTHu6LQ7hisGvJGPXUuYygGEpuOCakxSDT3p7cFLRZhjYEjPpTf2jTNZYHoamSRxLdsuJ5rn4it4YCdcX-zcvZUQJBjQD7-pZGF797sNshiJ7mM9CBDF75zm1TdaBbhqWhc6RbKte1dsaLWNDhW02ljlD9Lu4tr5pUFVriWnu5kOwdxpKkTJcAN6BfyuIMZh_fZC9nuXC2OTa09p6Oxa_B7eWg6UxfbKZGNOqG6BPJshtlXswdFxXV9YeK8aqW2Y4gq0IAr6Q_JboXgkHcafeGm9FOj9rj5hu_oTtjM3lDi_UXB6MXAeKUisYnlSkYWmaBwiYuMllmljgHMa89AwiphcXTrPtXIZNE7UxM3rJt9vn5XY7GM35TIzH3z08n34f8EfTbxd1LZqdNUQpUaDIxrrv7Cd5dLfmqavdBdg7bDhLj2qHcqXQbWUvwN4P5Kysq-MzKcmm95inSWSb1kLXUS3lbc7FvuJLgl18Ya6f1Tax9DMwHH7q_GehcUPJ3gAjdA2aZ8yocEHTMmFwLcqMSYOFfdU3CDSx6jUnoIqU68HOK3GIMVRvNNqba8-mjNNmFgDdYeUc7iE95HNjS24Q8kSoAlc2LFOiNRPd-QCXSVYQRGJ7PgAMMKe4g8yx8EOTVlUbo24ozWMKhvZqgj2pDKtxzxrzAElzetONv0Fnn42ZP1WmZo2S8ItquN1TQplHQtO3jooD6wzshqjrv_u0DbHLwUniGOOEtVqY3Y03ouORecS1NIsLp41zfY-Htn86l3tbxIq4p4kN0KwKhoI7S-xIuuPYRWFPU8FmHxMHnu6H5H9q_vyyLeMCV8v80pj4n900nfxS4_qs9uPHyAqz6Nqz53X0LseD8dhkcd69sO3eZA69mRcl--CXjN7WPXLobdi_1JiNa95r7ot0f56Xs79KvTz_8e9fzp-IigRxkMwuAjqbBmKQ3FU3M088iv1JMjAsikz8Bjdjek7wNzmPB4pA_PibK3JJxlM5iQfiyYw2jTP6cTn_YeGuHz64818)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```ruby
->n{a,b,d=0,c=1,n
while n>=c
k=(n+b)/d
a,b,c,d=c,d,k*c-a,k*d-b
puts b<2?a:a*1r/b
end}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3Q3Xt8qoTdZJ0UmwNdJJtDXXyuMozMnNSFfLsbJO5sm018rSTNPVTuEBKkoGKgFgnWytZNxFIpugmcRWUlhQrJNkY2SdaJWoZFukncaXmpdRCDF-SFm0WC2EuWAChAQ)

Comment: I think you need `n>=c` for the case `n=1`.

Comment: @Arnauld Looks like you’re right, thanks.

Comment: [-4](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3Q3Xt8qoTdZJ0UmwNdJJtDXXyuMozMnNSFfLsbJO5sm018rSTNPVTuEBKkoGKgFgnWytZNxFIpugmcRWUlhQrJNkY2SdaJWoZFukncaXmpdRCDF-SFm0WC2EuWAChAQ) using ruby's fractions

Comment: @Razetime Thanks! I had tried that but used `p` instead of `puts`, which gives output formatted like `(1/6)`. I didn't realize `puts` would give the right output!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.matrices`,  <sup><s>83 76</s></sup>  71 bytes

```factor
[ [1,b] 1 over n/v outer [ [ 1 min ] map ] gather natural-sort stack. ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU0xDsIwDNz7Cj-AFnVBCB5QsbAgpqpDCGmImibFcSrxFpYOwJ_6G1zCYt-d787PTyskeZxmfT4djtUOekG3AoXTKkCn0CmbJB5oJIs_Nqol9ScerwohqHtUbnEEj2ScZoUCDKiIHgMaR7DPss07Uptv56qGulxdGijBj5x26xF8JEZ8YLE3DhquH3hqfrJYBEUUNl_qIZCQXQFNqntJYW2C05T2Fw)

##### How?

In Factor, division produces ratios that automatically reduce to simplified form, so that helps a lot.

- `[1,b] 1 over n/v outer` If \$x\$ is the input, \$\Bigl[1\ldots x\Bigr]\otimes\Bigl[\frac{1}{1}\ldots\frac{1}{x}\Bigr]\$ (where \$\otimes\$ is the tensor/outer product).
- `[ [ 1 min ] map ] gather` Get a list of the unique elements of the above matrix whose values are clamped to a maximum of 1.
- `natural-sort` Sort into ascending order.
- `stack.` Print each ratio to stdout with a newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
j{mj\//Ri.*dd<oc.*N^SQ2sUQ)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6s6NytGXz8oU08rJcUmP1lPyy8uONCoODRQ0/D/fzMA)

###### Explanation

```
j{mj\//Ri.*dd<oc.*N^SQ2sUQ)1 | Full code
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   ^SQ2      | Generate all pairs of integers [1..input]
              oc.*N          | Sort by division
             <         sUQ   | Keep only the first <input>th triangular number of pairs (the next pair is always [1, 1])
  m   /Ri.*dd                | Divide each pair by its GCD
  mj\/                       | Join each pair by '/'
 {                           | Remove duplicates
j                         )  | Join all by '\n'
                             | Print (implicit)
                           1 | Print 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 99 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 a,b,c,d=0,1,1,n
 while~n+c:k=(n+b)//d;a,b,c,d=c,d,k*c-a,k*d-b;print([1,f"{a}/{b}"][b>1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3k1NS0xTSNPI0rbgUEnWSdJJ1UmwNdAyBMI9LoTwjMye1Lk872SrbViNPO0lTXz_FGqYKiHWytZJ1E4Fkim6SdUFRZl6JRrShTppSdWKtfnVSrVJsdJKdYawmxKqlaRqGBlA2zHoA)

Another port of the [Farey sequence generation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Next_term), though this one's a bit cheaty since the code on the Wikipedia article is given in Python.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
¨Vv/fU~ṅs⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCqFZ2L2ZVfuG5hXPigYsiLCIiLCI2Il0=)

```
¨Vv/fU~ṅs⁋
¨Vv/        # Create a division table from [1, input]
    fU      # Flatten and uniquify
      ~ṅ    # Keep only elements <= 1
        s   # Sort
         ⁋  # Join on newlines
```